# Yammer Button quit working today

Tags: yammer

I have two different App IDs and they both stopped working today.

I am using the Login button and this has worked fine for 1 for over a year and the other on Azure for over month.

They are not working in Visual Studio either, which they both did until today.

Our Service Side Authentication is still working on the latest version of our app but we keep the old one up.

The button is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="(Removed For Security Reasons)" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

Has anything changed on Yammer's end in the last 48 hours?

Comment: 25 days went by and today it started working; I didn't change anything in the code so I guess Yammer got around to fixing something on their end.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing to fix, after 25 days Yammer finally did something and now it works again. I didn't change any code so now the issue can be closed.